# How to store dynamic data in local memory : Android

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences, android-file

I have a product page with spinner. Spinner contains list of products. Dynamic views will be create by selecting product. No.of fields will be differ for each product. Fields may contain Edittext, Spinner. After user complete columns there is a save button to save filled details. Once user press the save button all fields value should be store in local.

I tried to save details in SQLite but sqlite only for structured datas. I am confused which local storage will be support for dynamic datas.

Please suggest any solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may serialize the result-object into json - and then store that json everywhere (sharedstorage, sqlite etc)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and fastest solution: you can have all the possible fields in the database and then store null values.

Best solution: Have multiple tables for all the different types of products that you can have and store the data there appropriately.